# Prove that the set of smooth points in any irreducible complex variety is connected.

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Prove that the set of smooth points in any irreducible complex variety is connected.

If one pick an algebraic curve over $R$ wich a cuspidal singularity, then after removing this singularity we get something not connected in general.

When it is a smooth complex variety, it might be solved by Reimann Removable singularity Theorem.

Comment: when complex manifolds,cf E.M.Chrika **Complex Analytic Sets** 5.3 Irreducibility p55 Proposition.

Comment: Take a look at chapter 2 of Griffiths' Introduction to Algebraic Curves.